# Chrome.tabs.update adding chrome-extension://

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a simple page action that turns on when a specific url is recognized, modifies the url and updates the tab with the new url.

Below is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name" : "SF Attachment",
  "version" : "1.1",
  "description" : "Open a SF attachment",
  "background" : 
  {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
     "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :
  {
  "default_icon" : "icon19.png",
  "default_title" : "Open link"
  },
  "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
  "icons" : 
  {
     "19" : "icon19.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And my background.js:

```
function checkForValidURL(tabId, info, tab) {   
   var idx = tab.url.indexOf('file:///C:/Users/sk/Downloads');
   if (idx > -1) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);

      chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)
      {
         chrome.tabs.create({url: "www.google.com"});
      });
   } else {
      chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
   }
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidURL);
```

For now, I'm redirecting to google.com but the new url actually gets sent as 
`chrome-extension://najbfggahgkmlcifdoamdhgdllbkafeg/www.google.com`.
I read about web-accessible-resources and how this format of url is used by the extension for local files but that's not my situation and I don't believe I have that enabled anywhere, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 4):

URLs in `tabs.create` (and virtually any other URLs on the Web, e.g., `window.open` or `<a>` links) that do not begin with a scheme are treated as relative paths from the page currently running the script.

You must include a scheme, e.g. `https://www.google.com`.